# Making the calendar stay on a specified month

Tags: 7, javascript

I am using the FullCalendar module for Drupal 7. I need to set the calendar to stay in a specific month and not change months according to the actual current month. Im assuming that as soon as it hits January, the calendar will switch to the month of January.

FullCalendar also highlights the current day of the month in yellow. Is there an option to disable that feature?

I tried looking through the options in views and fullcalendar's settings, but was not successful. My guess is that I have to edit some of the javascript inside the module or create a custom calendar. (which I found the  [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1342772)  to be a little confusing)

I just started drupal 2 weeks ago so im still trying to get the hang of it.

Thanks in advance